# Inserting a file without altering the folder's modification timestamp?

Tags: bash, shell, files, filesystems, ext4

I have hundreds of folders with modification timestamps I'd like to preserve.
Now I need to copy a single file into them.

Aside from this way...

```
timestamp=$(stat -c %y /foldername)
cp /tmp/file.jpg /foldername/file.jpg
touch -d "$timestamp" /foldername
```

...is there a better way to suppress the folder modification timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use `touch -r`. In `zsh`:

```
() {
  touch -r $2:h -- $3 && cp -T -- $2 $3 && touch -r $3 -- $2:h
} /tmp/file.jpg /foldername/file.jpg =(:)
```

Where `=(:)` creates an empty temporary file that is deleted as soon as the anonymous function terminates. `-T` (to force the `cp` to be a *copy-to* and never a *copy-into*) is a GNU extension.

Or make is a function, here allowing extra options to be passed along to `cp`:

```
copy_while_preserving_mtime_of_target_directory() {
  # Usage: ... [cp options] source dest
  () {
    touch -r "$@[-1]:h" -- "$1" &&
      cp -T "$@[2,-1]" &&
      touch -r "$1" -- "$@[-1]:h"
  } =(:) "$@"
}
```

Another approach could be some function that takes arbitrary shell code as argument and wraps its execution inside something that saves and restores the directory's mtime:

```
run_while_preserving_mtime_of() {
  # Usage: ... directory shell-code
  () {
    touch -r "$2" -- "$1" || return
    {
      eval -- "$@[3,-1]"
    } always {
      touch -r "$1" -- "$2"
    }
  } =(:) "$@"
}
```

To use as:

```
run_while_preserving_mtime_of /foldername '
  cp /tmp/file.jpg /foldername/file.jpg
'
```

for instance.

Comment: Are there any negative aspects when files inside a folder are newer than the last modification date of the folder?

Comment: @lmoly, no, it's common for directories to have files newer than them in them. Directories are not modified when you modified a file in them. Only when you modify the directory (rename an entry in them or add/remove an entry). Also remember a file can be linked to more than one directory (have a corresponding entry in more than one directory).